# EmguCV close abruptly when debug from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, emgucv

When i add Emgu.CV Refenrece

- Emgu.CV.dll
- Emgu.CV.UI.dll
- Emgu.Util.dll

and try to debug in Visual studio 2010 (press the F5 key) then application close abruptly without any warn or alert.

my app have a MainWindow and open a new Window, qhen i try to open the second window (Contain Emgu.CV.Capture) the app close without warn or throw exception

Comment: Have you tested the Example.CameraCapture.exe example in the bin directory ? When I first tried OpenCV it was crashing because my camera was already in use by another program (Skype).

Comment: i've solved the problem, later shared my answer